# Sort giving unexpected output!

Tags: sorting

I want to perform sorting on a list of strings, If i take for example the list `s`

```
s = {"test9","test8","test10"};
```

If I perform the Sort function I will get:

```
{test10, test8, test9}
```

I want the sort to do it in a normal way

```
{test8, test9, test10}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, "1" is lexicographically before "8" and "9", so the result you get is correct: test10 < text8 < test9

Comment: kevin, your question has been asked and answered before.  Please see the link inserted at the top of your post.

Comment: Okay thanks, i found the answer in the link